# IdentityServer4 providing miss formatted supported-scopes

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect, scopes

the issue is that i have a project with .net core 3.1 and reactjs called tv-participants-lookup and after implementing and configuring serveridentity4 and when trying to register or login it returns an Invalid Scope error, hence the problem is as shown bellow in the .well-known/openid-configuration:

```
{
    "issuer": "https://localhost:5001",
    "jwks_uri": "https://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
    "authorization_endpoint": "https://localhost:5001/connect/authorize",
    "token_endpoint": "https://localhost:5001/connect/token",
    "userinfo_endpoint": "https://localhost:5001/connect/userinfo",
    "end_session_endpoint": "https://localhost:5001/connect/endsession",
    "check_session_iframe": "https://localhost:5001/connect/checksession",
    "revocation_endpoint": "https://localhost:5001/connect/revocation",
    "introspection_endpoint": "https://localhost:5001/connect/introspect",
    "device_authorization_endpoint": "https://localhost:5001/connect/deviceauthorization",
    "frontchannel_logout_supported": true,
    "frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
    "backchannel_logout_supported": true,
    "backchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
    "scopes_supported": [
        "openid",
        "profile",
        "API.ClientId",
        "TV Participants lookupAPI", **<=======** you may notice the space between the words causing it to appear like three scopes when validating the scopes
        "offline_access"
    ],
```

and this is my appsettings.json:

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "client1": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA",
        "AlowedScopes":"openid profile"
      
      }
    },
    "Resources": {
      "API.ClientId": {
        "Profile": "API"
      }
    } 
},
```

startup.cs as follows:

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
         services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>                      options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(("DefaultConnection"))));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
         .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()     
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();          
        services.AddAuthorization();
           services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role;
    });
        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();
        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

So the question is from where is the openid-connect is getting that scope -"TV Participants lookupAPI"-from ?? and is there a way to remove or alter the scopes_supported ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out as I had to change the project name and remove the spaces. Once the `.csproj` is named `TV_Participants_lookupAPI` the problem has been resolved.